# Where did my compose key go?

Tags: compose-key

In 19.04 and before, I could press <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> and the Compose Key would trigger. I could then enter a mythical combination of characters and it would output a nice unicode char.

-> turned into ⭢
(c) turned into ©

These were useful things for somebody who likes to argue on the internet.

But I don't seem to be able to do that since upgrading to 19.10. The Gnome Tweak box that claims to re-enable it (it was disabled on first boot) has not helped. I have tried several settings with it.

[image: Compose key settings]

It works on my laptop. I have compared the keypresses in `xev` and they have the same code.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x1e9, subw 0x0, time 160318302, (1465,1753), root:(1505,1791),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xff20, Multi_key), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True
```

So why isn't my <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> triggering compose?

Comment: I have tried it in Fresh Install of Ubuntu 19.10 working as intended. Seems Upgrade is the issue in your case as every upgrade have some issues.. Thank You.

Comment: This seems to have fixed itself after a reboot. I don't reboot very often (suspend most of the time) so.. yeah. ☺